# The extent of closeness

Tags: adjective-degrees

"She came and sat **by/beside/close to/next to/near** me." To me, the bold lettered prepositions seem to have almost the same meaning.
Is there any difference between them? If so, would you arrange them in order of the degree of closeness? From the closest to the least closest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my personal interpretation from the PoV of an English person.

In order from closest to least close:

- Close to / beside / next to / by / near

That is from my perspective. Others may differ.

- "Close to" signifies intimacy and affection.
- "Beside" signifies unity in aim, e.g. soldiers fighting beside each other; two people on a podium presenting to the public; and so on.
- "Next to" signifies arrangement into ranks: similar to "beside" but without the context of the close collaboration that "beside" portrays.
- "By" is more along the lines "in company with", although the famous song "stand by me" seems to indicate something along the lines of "beside". Grey area, this one.
- "Near" just means "in the general vicinity of".

My mother once relates the tale of how one time she was sitting in a cafeteria where she worked, and a colleague whose English was not native approached her and asked: "May I sit close to you?" and my mother laughed and gave him an English lesson: "*This* is what it means to sit close to one another," and she snuggled up to him.

Comment: Ehh... depends on context. "She sat close to me" implies intimacy. "I got to sit close to the President of the United States" is maybe a bit strange (I'd use *near*), but no one would think you were snuggling up to the President.

Comment: **By, beside** and **next to** could all refer to taking the adjacent seat in a public place (bus, concert hall, or church, for example), which could suggest a wish for intimacy or, if the place is crowded, just be the result of chance. **Near to** doesn't necessarily mean 'in the next seat'.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski In which case I would not use the words "close to" the President. If I *were* to use it, I would assume it had the sense "because we were about to work on something together that required our physical proximity, because we may have been about to discuss things of privacy and confidentiality". So perhaps a lawyer would "sit close" to his client -- and indeed, the term still has connotations of intimacy and interpersonal privacy.

Comment: @KateBunting Different people may have different ideas of the *exact* nuances (note my disclaimer) - but if someone sat on the seat on the bus adjacent to the one I was on, I would use the term "next to", unless the person knew me and had a reason for sitting "beside" me (e.g. we were travelling together and needed to ensure we were not separated). "By" would work in both circumstances but would be used where the specific physical locations and personal interrelations are not all that important. "Near", as you say, does not imply adjacency.

Comment: I'm much clearer now. Thank you for your elaborate answer, Mr. Mover. And Ms. Bunting, thank you for your clear explanation again. Also Mr. Stachowski, thank you for your nice comment.